# setting calender fields with roll method

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have following code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(2013, 12, 31);
System.out.println(c.getTime() + " " +c.DATE + " " + c.MONTH + " " + c.YEAR);
c.roll(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println(c.getTime() + " " +c.DATE + " " + c.MONTH + " " + c.YEAR);
```

What I am excepting is my date c is set to 31 December 2013 and when I one to the month without changing the larger field roll method should add one to month to get January...
But I get output as follows :

```
Tue Dec 31 13:49:51 EST 2013 5 2 1
Thu Jan 31 13:49:51 EST 2013 5 2 1
```

why c.Date, c.Month and year return these values .. any idea??

I am referring javadocs for understanding,are there any other websites which could explain these fields better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Calendar#roll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll-int-int-) will just *roll* (increase/decrease) the value of the *field* you specify and won't update the other *fields* in the `Calendar`. Since you're rolling the month, only month will be affected, not year not day nor any other field.

Also, note that `Calendar#DATE`, `Calendar#MONTH` and `Calendar#YEAR` are constants to the class, they're not the fields. Use [`Calendar#get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get-int-) instead:

```
System.out.println(c.getTime() + " " + c.get(Calendar.DATE) + " " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + " " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

because [`DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE), [`MONTH`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH), [`YEAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) are int constants used internally by [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

you need

```
c.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

to retrieve DATE field

**Note:**
also month starts from `0` in `Calendar` so `12` would be `January` instead of `December`